# Unable to create SSIS Integration Runtime on Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I'm having an error when i try to create my SSIS Integration Runtime on Azure Data Factory :

Microsoft.Batch resource provider is not registered under the same subscription of VNet

[image]

And here is the detail of the error :
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A resource provider is a service that supplies the resources you can deploy and manage through Resource Manager. Each resource provider offers a set of resources and operations for working with an Azure service. For example, if you want to store keys and secrets, you work with the Microsoft.KeyVault resource provider.

It appears the SSIS Integration runtime requires a batch account. But you are not able to provision a batch account because the resource provider is not registered. To register a resource provider, you must have permission to perform the /register/action operation for the resource provider. This operation is included in the Contributor and Owner roles.

You can use PowerShell to register it:

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Batch
```

You can also register it through the portal. Go to Subscriptions -> Resource Providers. Search for Microsoft.Batch and click the register link on that result.

You can find more info in the MS Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services#portal).

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you join the SSIS Integration Runtime to Azure VNet.

Go to your Subscription -> Resource Provider -> Microsoft.Batch and register it.

Microsoft.Batch is required because when you join the Integration Runtime to the VNet, Azure, behind the scenes uses Azure Batch service to provision necessary resources like Load Balancer, NSG, Public IP to continue the communication even after IR is within the VNet